# Average/Median Bitcoin Holdings for US

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, exchanges

They said 17% of US Residents own bitcoin, or 46 million americans.

Just curious if anyone knows the median/average amount for these people. $100? $500? $10,000? I am trying to find statistics on this.

https://www.nasdaq.com/articles/about-46-million-americans-now-own-bitcoin-2021-05-14

Note on Statistics: Prefer Median Amount over Mean Average (since Median is not affected by extremely high net worth individuals, which can skew average).

Comment: This is impossible to know. Maybe take the US avg/median savings account to give you an idea of what Americans typically save, but as for avg/median bitcoin holdings nobody knows.

Comment: hi @m1xolyd1an would this website answer the question? https://bitinfocharts.com/top-100-richest-bitcoin-addresses.html it seems to, thanks

Comment: Addresses have very little to do with ownership. One person can have multiple wallets, and every wallet can contain multiple addresses. In the other direction, many coins are probably held custodially, where one wallet (and its address(es)) may hold funds that belong to multiple people.

Comment: how is this question opinion based? its asking for a fact @PieterWuille

Comment: @mattsmith5 while there is some factual number that describes bitcoin ownership, it is unknowable, so any answer to this question would largely be a matter of opinion. re: the bitcoin rich-list: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91242/bitcoin-rich-list-reliable-or-not/91243#91243

Comment: I did not vote to close this question. I'm just pointing out that address balances do not help inform an answer to it.